# Text search with Condition in Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have below scenario where, I have one collection "demo" having all data which need to be search,
I have used text search,

```
{
    "_id" : "1", 
    "type" : "Deal", 
    "description_title" : "New Deal for test", 
    "images" : "", 
    "start_date" : ISODate("2017-07-20T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "end_date" : ISODate("2017-10-30T11:59:00.000+0000"), 
    "status" : "1"
}
{
    "_id" : "2", 
    "type" : "Event", 
    "description_title" : "Event1 test", 
    "images" : "", 
    "end_date" : ISODate("2017-10-20T00:00:00.000+0000")
    "status" : "1"
}
{
    "_id" : "3", 
    "type" : "Text", 
    "description_title" : "test", 
    "images" : "",
    "status" : "1"
}
{
    "_id" : "4", 
    "type" : "Event", 
    "description_title" : "Event2 test", 
    "images" : "", 
    "end_date" : ISODate("2017-07-20T00:00:00.000+0000")
    "status" : "1"
}
```

In above collection I have stored all data which need to be search by using text search, But when `"type" : "Event"/"Deal"` then it should only return Active Deals & Events `"Current date is less than end_date"` need to be searched.
In above collection When I search for "Test", It should return,

```
{
    "_id" : "1", 
    "type" : "Deal", 
    "description_title" : "New Deal for test", 
    "images" : "", 
    "start_date" : ISODate("2017-07-20T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "end_date" : ISODate("2017-10-30T11:59:00.000+0000"), 
    "status" : "1"
}
{
    "_id" : "2", 
    "type" : "Event", 
    "description_title" : "Event1 test", 
    "images" : "", 
    "end_date" : ISODate("2017-10-20T00:00:00.000+0000")
    "status" : "1"
}
{
    "_id" : "3", 
    "type" : "Text", 
    "description_title" : "test", 
    "images" : "",
    "status" : "1"
}
```

I have used below query, but it gives me all result,

```
    db.demo.find({'$text' : {'$search' => 'test'},'$or' : {
    {"type" : "Deal","end_date" : {'$gte' : ISODate("2017-09-14T11:59:00.000+0000") }},
    {"type" : "Text"},
{"type" : "Event","end_date" : {'$gte' : ISODate("2017-09-14T11:59:00.000+0000") }},
    }})
```

Above query return all records.
Please help me to achieve my result.

Comment: use textScore and in the end use limit(1), by doing this you will get 1 document which is matching exactly. Check the doc
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-operator-text-score